# Unable to connect with mysql (forgot password)

Tags: php, mysql

I am using xampp-1.7.2 on windows-7. I forgot my mysql password or some other setting is done wrongly. Even I am not able to use localhost/phpmyadmin. It is giving below error-

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I reinstalled the xammp as well but still the same problem is occurring. Kindly suggest how this problem can be addressed.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: mysqld -nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt worked for me. please put your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html
```

Have a look ;)

cmd:
 or wherever xampp/mysql/bin exists

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin"
C:\> mysqld -nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

mysql-init.txt:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```